# I used npm cache clean --force and an error occured when I create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I'm a beginner in ReactJs so I'm sorry if this is a very noob question. I need help. I used npm cache clean --force because there was another error and a site recommended i use npm cache clean --force. Now, I can't create a react app. I tried reinstalling NodeJS.

```
C:\Users\Name\Desktop>npx create-react-app my-app
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:327
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\is-promise\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:319:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:967:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\run-async\index.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Name\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\create-react-app\\node_modules\\is-promise\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'is-promise'
}
```

Please help me. I need to create a react app because I want to be practice it.[screenshot of node_modules folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvZHG.png)

```
C:\Users\Name\Desktop>npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\package.json'
npm WARN Desktop No description
npm WARN Desktop No repository field.
npm WARN Desktop No README data
npm WARN Desktop No license field.

up to date in 1.433s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

This is what happens when I try to install npm.

Comment: Try to remove `C:\Users\\Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` folder and install create-react-app (`npm i -g create-react-app`) again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the output of the command `node -v && npm -v` ? it should be something like

```
v12.16.0
6.13.4
```

Then, you could do

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g create-react-app
npx create-react-app my-app-name
cd my-app-name
npm start
```

Comment: wow thank you so much!! i've been trying to figure this out for days. Thank you!

Comment: aha, i wasn't sure, to be honest ;)  I'm glad that it works now!